# How to sort string in ascending order based upon the integers that are part of this string

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I have a list in this format:

```
hwy = [[3, NYC, NY, ['I-40', 'I-30','I-55']],[2, Chicago, IL, ['I-20','I-25','I-   12']],......]
```

I want to print out the interstates, hwy[3], but in ascending order so that for the first list in hwy would look something like this:

```
>> Interstates: I-30, I-40, I-55
```

So as you can see they are in ascending order based on the `int` part of `I-int`.

How could I go about sorting them based on what I said above.

Comment: are the strings always in the same format? i mean I-<integer>

Comment: @kroolik I used `split()` twice so that I could access the integer portion and sort them using the `sort()` function. The problem is that it doesn't affect hwy[3].

Comment: @markcial Yes the format is always constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

**this works:**

```
for i in hwy:
    i[3].sort() # changes the element(list) in place

for i in hwy:
    i[3] = sorted(i[3]) # this will change the element in hwy also
```

The above have basically the same effect.

**OR**

```
for i in hwy:
    i[3] = sorted(i[3], key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[-1]))
    #the key here may be necessary if your format for the lists wasn't consistent
```

It does however assume that the list with interstate numbers is always the 3rd item in each list within hwy

`x.split('-')` splits the interstates by the `'-'` character. the `[-1]` slice notation
specifies the last member of the resulting list.

Comment: there is no need for key OP said that format is constant, sorted is enough

Comment: @Totem does sorted() change the actual `hwy[3]` in `hwy`?

Comment: @user3250673, compared to `list.sort()` which modifies the list in-place, `sorted` returns a new list which is a sorted version of the argument.

Comment: @Totem so if I wanted to actually modify the list so that all of the  `hwy[3]` were sorted I could just use `for i in range(len(hwy)):
    hwy[i][3].sort()`

Comment: @Totem, why not `for el in hwy: el[3].sort()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you need to do a numerical sort (I-300 comes after I-40).

You can simply define a custom compare function.

```
>>> hwy
[[3, 'NYC', 'NY', ['I-40', 'I-30', 'I-55']], [2, 'Chicago', 'IL', ['I-20', 'I-25', 'I-12']]
>>> [sorted(i[3], cmp = lambda x, y: int(x[2:]) - int(y[2:])) for i in hwy]
[['I-30', 'I-40', 'I-55'], ['I-12', 'I-20', 'I-25']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = ['I-40', 'I-30','I-55']

print map(i.sort(),i)
```

'>>>['I-30', 'I-40', 'I-55']

Comment: map first argument is a function; second argument are correspondent function input arguments. Then map apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results. [map documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```
[sorted(s_in, key = lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1])) for s_in in [h_4[3] for h_4 in hwy]]
```

Explanation:

```
# list of all 3rd elements
[h_3[3] for h_3 in hwy]

# sorts by the number part of the string, in each string in the list
sorted(s_in, key = lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
```